# call SAOP request in ADF mobile

Tags: soap, oracle-adf

I want to call SOAP request using ADF mobile. My request is :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:mustUnderstand="1"><wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Username>INDIA</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">welcome</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header>
    <soap:Body xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/mobile/Notificationlist">
        <ns1:NotificationlistRetrievalREQ>
            <ns1:NotificationlistType>HR_OFFER</ns1:NotificationlistType>
            <ns1:Status>TODO</ns1:Status>
            <ns1:Mode/>
        </ns1:NotificationlistRetrievalREQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So, I have call simple SOAP service without security header. But I have no idea that how to pass security header in ADF mobile.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Web Service Data Control and configure it to pass the security authentication you shouldn't need to mess around with the header manually.
See:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/accessing_secure_web_services_from

Comment: Thanks for reply.  But it is not helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a Provider class that extends SOAPProvider class and implementing getAdditionalSoapHeaders method within it. Set the various headers in this method and modify the DataControls.dcx file to point to your Provider class.
I have explained one such usecase in my [blog post here.](http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/07/passing-custom-soap-headers-in-adf.html)